# Convert sql query into Django query set?

Tags: sql, django, database

```sql
SELECT * from quiz_quiz where subject_id=(SELECT subject_id from general_subject_assignment where grade_id =(SELECT grade_id from general_student where user_id =2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear `@Madhan Umk`You can get records from django models by getting models one by one e.g.

1. Fetch required student from `general_student`
2. After that fetch required subject from `general_subject_assignment`
3. then fetch all quiz data from `quiz_quiz` by assigning above subject.

   Django query set

   `grade = general_student.objects.filter(user_id = 2)`

   `grade_id = grade.id`

   `subject = general_subject_assignment.objects.filter(grade_id = grade_id)`

   `subject_id = subject.id`

   `quizs = quiz_quiz.objects.filter(subject_id = subject_id)`

Hope you will get the idea. If you have any question let know.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in one line

```
quiz.objects.filter(subject=general_subject_assignment.objects.get(grade_id=general_student.objects.get(user_id=2).grade_id))
```